# Firebase spend and AdMob ads

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, admob, ads

I would like to ask you a question about the value of Firebase and AdMob ad earnings with an Android app. I am creating an application that uses a lot of Firebase Realtime Database as it is a social networking app, has messaging, multi-person group messaging, profile visiting, and more. I will only use Firebase as a database, so it will have a lot of value stored there. And the only way the app will have (for now) make money is banner admob ads (which will get on all app screens) and some interstitial ads. It is an app where users will spend a lot of time on it as it will be a social network, so ads will be displayed all the time.

The problem is that I'm afraid that at the end of the month Firebase's monthly price will be more expensive than the ad revenue for the month (I'll use the Blaze plan, which pays as you go). Can user visualization in ads be worth the price of their own readings, inclusions and exclusions of values ​​in Realtime Database? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how long it takes for you to get many people using the app.
When each screen that contains a banner ad loads, it's calculated as a page view.
The more people that use your app will drive up the amount you get paid for Page RPM (Revenue Per Mille which = 1000 views).
Obviously you require a separate banner ad unit for each page, so if the app has a few pages which load, they should add up quickly with many users.
The amount is only small though, usually a couple of dollars for Page RPM, the interstitial ads pay much more but will be an inconvenience for the user.
People get used to ignoring the banner ads as long as they don't interfere
with the functionality of the app, the interstitial ads need to be placed strategically.
My two apps which I've had published in the last 10 days don't have many users yet and have totalled around 3000 page views in that time which looks to only be around $6 (for the last 10 days).
In the same time, only 300 impressions which are around $20 per 1000.
I have 3 banners and two interstitial.
I'm trying to build up the number of users at the moment which will cost more in advertising too.

Comment: Gotcha! I created one ad unit for each page, it's 6 banner units and 2 interstitial units, hopefully right. Good luck with your apps and thanks for the reply :)